# responseBlock runs at the end of api call objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have to store specific movies url in database to show in collectionView which is inside a table cell. Whenever it compiles to this line `[API userMovies:catId getResponseBlock:^(id responseObject)` it goes to this line `_movieImages = [Movies MR_findAll]` instead of `responseBlock`.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  static int number = 0;
    catId = [[_movieCategories objectAtIndex:number] categoryId];
    number++;
    [API userMovies:catId getResponseBlock:^(id responseObject)
     {
         [Movies MR_truncateAll];
         [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];     
         NSArray *responseArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"items"];      
         [Movies MR_importFromArray:responseArray];
         [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];      
     } forFailureBlock:^(id failureObject) {
         //             self.errorMsg.text = @"Failed to load movies!";
     }];
       _movieImages = [Movies MR_findAll];
    return _movieImages.count;
}
```

**cellForItemAtIndexPath:**

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        CategoryCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CatCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_movieImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cover_img]];
        NSNumber *rate = [[_movieImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]rating];


        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
        _categoryCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        return cell;
    }
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *categoryTable = @"CategoryCell";

    // Configure the cell...
        CategoryMovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:categoryTable];
        cell.categoryMovie.text = [[_movieCategories objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] name];
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your doing this wrong way. Create a function of that API Call, after that call that function. In that api call on success part reload the collection view.

Comment: how to reload the collectionView?

Comment: [collectionView reloadData];

Comment: Here collectionView is Outlet object of UICollectionView. In your case put the outlet name that you created.

Comment: thanks a lot @NiravDoctorwala, it solves my one problem which was that when I was scrolling collection view previous collection view cells were get disappear. But one thing still persists which is that all collection views are showing the same data.

Comment: In your different UITableCell. Right?

Comment: yeah. I did some changes again and now different data is loading in each tableCell but again after scrolling data gets disappears

Comment: Can you put some code of cell for row at index path and cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: `CategoryCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CatCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_movieImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cover_img]];
    NSNumber *rate = [[_movieImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]rating];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
    _categoryCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;`

Comment: Not here edit your question with your code

Comment: one this more, one of `UITableCell` working fine but all others are not working with scroll. and that Okay cell always have same data.

Comment: Don't get it what are you trying to say.

Comment: For your collectionView delegate and datasource it is bind with Tableviewcell?

Comment: If not you have to change that

Comment: I am little confuse about delegates and data source I had just added `<UICollectionViewDataSource>` in `UITableViewCell`